# How do I modify the default styles in Word 2007

Tags: ms-word

How do I modify the default styles in Word 2007.

I need to change the style "Intense Emphasis" from blue to red. Updating the Normal.dotm works well and good when I open up a new 2007 document, **BUT** when I open a 2003 document via Word 2007 the "Intense Emphasis" is still blue.

How do I fix this? Do I need a macro?

Comment: I think this question belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, any changes you make to Normal.dotm only apply to new documents.

If you have a set of existing documents, and you want to change a style in all of them, the easiest thing to do would be to use a macro.  The OpenXML SDK could help you if you have a very large set of files you need to update.

Comment: But where is the "Intense Emphasis" style coming from? It must be coming from somewhere.

Comment: The style does not even exist in the documents because these styles did not exist in Word 2003. Word 2007 is placing them in there.